# "Could not determine the dependencies" warning in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am getting the following warnings in my VB.NET solution...

> Warning   5   Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference
>   "Excel". Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))  MyProject Warning   6   Could not
>   determine the dependencies of the COM reference "VBIDE". Error loading
>   type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A
>   (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)) MyProject

which make little sense to me. Ought I to worry about these?

If yes, what should I do about them?
If no, how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should worry about these warnings. You might not be able to create/edit Excel documents or something related those libraries.

I had the some problem. What I did to figure it out is that I removed those references and added them again. You should give your attention to which version of libraries you are adding like Excel 14.0 or 15.0